# How to pass Teamcity build parameters into an Ant script that is launched by Fake script?

Tags: ant, environment-variables, teamcity, f#-fake

I have an Ant `build.xml` which contains the following code:

```
<mkdir dir="c:/MyDir/${build.number}/html"/>
```

This works fine when I run this task as a separate TeamCity build step (as an Ant task).

I have moved the execution of this script into a Fake F# script. Now, when I execute the Fake script from Teamcity, the value of the parameter is not being set (it literally creates a folder with the name "${build.number}").

I launch my ant script in Fake like this:

```
let cmd = sprintf @"%s\plugins\ant\bin\ant.bat" (Configuration.agentHomeDir.ToString())
let args = ""
let dir = ""

Shell.Exec(cmd, args, dir)
```

How would I refer to Teamcity's build number from inside my ant script correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up passing the buildnumber via a command line argument.

in fake script:

```
let buildNumber = environVar "BUILD_NUMBER"
let cmd = sprintf @"%s\plugins\ant\bin\ant.bat" (Configuration.agentHomeDir.ToString())
let args = sprintf "-DbuildNumber=%s" buildNumber.ToString()
let dir = ""
Shell.Exec(cmd, args, dir)
```

in ant's build.xml:

```
<property name="buildNumber" value="buildNumber" />

...

<mkdir dir="c:\mydir\${buildNumber}" />
```

Would welcome a more graceful solution.